# How can I pass in generic HTML to an Angular 2 component?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to make a generic modal component that can hold anything, from just text to images/buttons etc. If I do something like this:

```
<div class="Modal">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="body">{{content}}</div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

I'm not able to actually pass HTML into content, just text. How can I create a component such that the parent component can pass in whatever HTML it wants? What if I wanted to add n number of buttons to the footer, each with it's own callback? Is there a better way I should be doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is `ng-content`

```
 <div class="Modal">
   <div class="header"></div>
   <div class="body">
     <ng-content></ng-content>
   </div>
   <div class="footer"></div>
 </div>
```

and you may pass any HTML content directly into your component.
Lets say your component name is `my-modal`, you may use it like below,

```
  <my-modal>
     <<HTML content :  this will be replaced in the ng-content area >>
  </my-modal>
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks. I also just discovered [innerHTML]. Is there an advantage to one approach over the other that you know of?

Comment: not checked the [innerHTML], check if binding works there? Also check if local variable can be assigned to it like from *ngFor loop? if it does i don't see any advantage of one over other.

Comment: `outerHTML` replaces the element where you apply it. `innerHTML` adds it as children.

Comment: This is a great answer.