# How to get inner html of Angular6 component and add it to component template?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-components

I want to be able to pass components and other html into other components in this way:

```
<app-container-component>
  <h3>All these items should be displayed in parent component</h3>
  <app-another-component></app-another-component>
</app-container-component>
```

How can I read inner items of container-component and render them inside component template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the concept of "@Input","@Output-EventEmitter".By using these properties you can pass data from parent component to child component using @Input decorator and from child to parent using @output decorator.
In your case app-container-component is the parent component and app-another-component is child component.
You can access the below URL for the complete understanding of these decorators:-

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Also in case if you want to pass HTML of component to other then you can use ContentChild or TemplateReferenceVariable. Refer below URL for other options:-

[How can I pass in generic HTML to an Angular 2 component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39085845/how-can-i-pass-in-generic-html-to-an-angular-2-component)

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answer. Seems that <ng-content></ng-content> is what I searched for