# Angular 2 component - multiple occurrences with the same selector

Tags: angular, typescript

I am given a component class with the following definition:

```
@component({
    selector: 'app-table',
    template: '<div #content></div>',
    styleUrls: ['./table.component.css']
});

export class TableComponent implements OnInit{
    @ViewChild('content') elm: ElementRef;
    ....
}
```

However, in the parent html, the structure is:

```
<div label="summary1">
   <app-table type="thisMonth"></app-table>
</div>
<div label="summary2">
   <app-table type="lastMonth"></app-table>
</div>
```

My question is, how can I put generate different content and put into the corresponding 'app-table'?

I tried to use the following method and it returns undefined:

```
export class TableComponent implements OnInit{
    @ViewChildren('content') elms: <QueryList>ElementRef;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use @Input() decorator to receive data from parent component i.e. "type" in your case.

Comment: @AkshayRana Thank you for the reply. So what I need to do is to declare: @Input() type: string; in the parent component, and new 2 TableaComponent objects in the parent component to generate corresponding content, is that correct?

Comment: No, you have to declare @Input() type: string; in the child component i.e. TableComponent, that means it is expecting an input named "type", now wherever you want to render this component you can send the type dynamically, like you are already doing here :    <app-table type="thisMonth"></app-table>.
So, in this case, you,ll get "thisMonth" as the value of type in Table component that is rendered for the above tag. After that you can build your logic in the Table component.

Answer (score 0):

As @Akshay Rana has mentioned in his comments that you have to use @Input decorator for passing data, he is absolutely correct. 
I am extending his answer in more detail. As you have asked that you need to generate different content and put into the corresponding 'app-table', if in case content is a HTML then only @Input decorator will not work. So I am sharing an URL where you can find all your answers,including the use of @Input,@Output decorator and all, please have a look and let me know if you need further more clarifications.
    [How to get inner html of Angular6 component and add it to component template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51106321/how-to-get-inner-html-of-angular6-component-and-add-it-to-component-template/51106577#51106577)

Comment: Thank you very much! I will refer to your URL and try again!